# MongoDB problema na listagem de dados com php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongoose

```js
var mongoose          = require('mongoose');
var db                = mongoose.connection;

// db connect
db.on('error', console.error);
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('Conectado ao MongoDB.')
});
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rotiny');
// -- //

var msnSchemaUser = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  username: String,
  password: String,
  email: String,
  roles: {
    type: Array,
    default: ['user']
  }
});

var msnModuleUser = mongoose.model('User', msnSchemaUser);

var query = msnModuleUser.find();
query.exec('find', function(err, items) {
    console.log(items)
});
```

> Resultados que o código retorna.

```
[ { roles: [ 'user' ],
    __v: 0,
    email: 'rotiny@rotyiny.com',
    password: '12345',
    username: 'rotiny',
    name: 'Rotiny - BETA API',
    _id: 5685e3f16d3e65ba3fa47e84 },
  { roles: [ 'user' ], __v: 0, _id: 5685e42f8deb044f405c6986 },
  { roles: [ 'user' ], __v: 0, _id: 5685e4e38deb044f405c6987 },
  { roles: [ 'user' ], __v: 0, _id: 5686068a8deb044f405c6988 },
  { roles: [ 'user' ], __v: 0, _id: 5686068a8deb044f405c6989 },
  { roles: [ 'user' ], __v: 0, _id: 5686068f8deb044f405c698a },
  { roles: [ 'user' ], __v: 0, _id: 568606908deb044f405c698b },
  { roles: [ 'user' ], __v: 0, _id: 5686069b8deb044f405c698c } ]
```

> Minha dúvida e a seguinte.

Porque não consigo lista, esses mesmos dados com esse código no PHP

```
$m = new Mongo("mongodb://localhost"); // connect
$db = $m->selectDB("rotiny");

$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'User');

$find = $collection->find();

foreach ($find as $doc) {
    var_dump($doc);
}
```

O código logo acima em php, não retorna nada.

> **Obs: faz pouco tempo que uso mongo.**

Alguém pode me dizer oque eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Nenhum erro é mostrado?

Comment: Não amigo, simplesmente não mostra nada.

Answer (score -1):

Tente usar a seguinte função para estabelecer conexão

```
    $m = new Mongo("mongodb://DATABASE_USERNAME:DATABASE_PASSWORD@HOST");
    $db = $m->selectDB($database); // Connect to Database
```

Caso não utilize senha:

```
    $m = new Mongo("mongodb://DATABASE_USERNAME@HOST");
    $db = $m->selectDB($database); // Connect to Database
```

Por exemplo

```
    $m = new Mongo("mongodb://root@localhost");
    $db = $m->selectDB($database); // Connect to Database
```

---

Vale ressaltar que o uso da classe `Mongo` foi descontinuada e o uso da `MongoDB` é recomendado. Veja mais em http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php

Comment: Eu não uso senha no mongo.

Comment: Utilize sem o `:DATABASE_PASSWORD` nesse caso.

Comment: Desculpa não fui especifico, eu não uso usuário e senha no mongo.

Comment: Estou vendo se mudando a class resolve, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Pois e amigo, eu não consigo pega os dados gravado com mongoose no php. vc pelo menos me ajudou a perceber isso, obrigado mesmo amigo! para resolver meu problema, tive que usa o modulo https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native.

Answer (score -1):

O driver mongo retorna um cursor e não um array PHP, você não vai debugar sua consulta com um var_dump como está fazendo em seu exemplo PHP, No caso do seu exemplo com mongoose para o node funciona a mesma lógica porque o mongoose é um ODM (Object Document Model) que se encarrega de usar as funções do driver do mongo para javascript que servem para manipular o cursor, e então ele faz a conversão dos resultados para um objeto te dando a possibilidade de manipular o retorno diretamente como objeto, o driver do Mongo para PHP não faz isto em todos seus métodos.

O ideal é você consultar na documentação do driver PHP quais os métodos que te retornam um array, e quais retornam um cursor, pelos exemplos você saberá como manipular os retornos de acordo com o método de consulta que está usando.

Referência oficial do driver PHP: https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/#drivers